# Mat Checkbox and Mat Radio not displaying properly in Angular Material 17.2.0

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular17

Angular material not displaying checkboxes and radio buttons properly im using angular 17 and angular material 17

```
"@angular/material": "17.2.0",
```

here is my code

```
<h1>Radio Buttons</h1>
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<br> <br> <br> <br>
<h1>Check Boxes</h1>

<section class="example-section">
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin">Yes</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin">No</mat-checkbox>
</section>
```

here is the outcome
[image]

You can see that even the shadow for these elements are displaced from the actual elements

I have tried updating my angular material

Comment: More than likely you have some project styles that are interfering with material styles. You can see the radio buttons work fine in this stackblitz linked from the material docs: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fexample%2Fradio-overview-example.html

Comment: It was being cause by box-sizing that i had set to border-box in my CSS for everything